# Where is conda-unpack script located?

Tags: python, conda, conda-pack

I'm trying to follow the steps at https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/index.html?highlight=conda%20unpack to pack & unpack a conda env.

However, I don't see the `conda-unpack` script.  Where should it be located?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `conda-unpack` script is in the `.tar.gz` that you have created with `conda-pack`. It is located in the `Scripts` folder of the extracted environment. It should therefore be available after unpacking and activating the environment.

Comment: I unpacked the `.tar.gz` created with `conda-pack`.  However, there is no `conda-unpack` in the `Scripts` folder.  Should `conda-unpack` always be created or are there times it's not needed & thus not created?

Comment: Did you, by any chance provide either of the `--dest-prefix PATH` or `-d PATH` option to `conda-pack`? In that case, no unpack script would be generated3

Comment: My last comment was incorrect.  When I used `conda-pack`, the `conda-unpack` method was located where your answered said it would be.  Thanks.

Comment: Ah okay, good to hear. Thanks for the update